# how to achieve spring security in java Swing and spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot, spring-security

I have developed Spring boot rest service. I have another Java Swing application which acts like client it accesses API's through Apache HttpClient library.
How can i achieve spring security between Java Swing and Spring boot.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) guide 
 to set up Spring security?

Comment: But this is for html , how can "/login"(login page) work in java swing.